# How to extract icon from executable using PHP?

Tags: php, windows, winapi, resources, exe

I need to extract the icon (.ico file) out of an executable (.exe).

I need it for PHP on Windows. Any Ideas?

Comment: Are you saying "I need to user PHP to extract ICO resources from EXE files"?  Please clarify, as "I need it for PHP" is a rather generic statement if you need a specific solution.

Comment: I don't get what's the problem here.. I need to be able to extract this ico with a PHP script.

Comment: And I don't get your tone.  People are trying to help you, try to be polite.  "I need it for PHP" doesn't specify whether you need a pure PHP solution, or whether you need to be able to manipulate inputs/outputs with PHP, or how exactly you want the interaction to go.  You mention asking a similar question before, but you don't link to your previous question so the rest of us lack whatever context you seem to assume exists.  Jon just edited your question, but please consider that prior to his edits your title did not adequately describe your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I originally thought that ImageMagick will extract icons from .exe files. However, it seems my memory is failing me.

Instead, since you are prepared to accept the use of `exec` I think the quickest and easiest solution will be to use a tool like ResHacker.  The can be driven in command-line mode. Then if you need to convert from .ico to .png, as per your last question, you can reach for ImageMagick.

Comment: WOW, running on php.net to check, maybe this is the final hit to finally abandon the awful GD in my framework

Comment: Checked, I don't think imageMagick can do that. I don't found any doc

Comment: hm i will check that reshacker